# radajaxmanager used for edit in radgrid clears my page heading

Tags: telerik, master-pages, telerik-grid, radajaxmanager, radajaxloadingpanel

i have an aspx page containing a radgrid. i placed the grid inside a radajax manager to ajaxify the inline edit and delete operations. the problem is that it makes my page head cleared. i did like this

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" >
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="radGdRatings">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="radGdRatings" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="radGdPobabilityMultiplier">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="radGdPobabilityMultiplier" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server" Skin="Office2007">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
```

in my content page.i mean i have not placed the radajaxmanager in the content page itself and not in the masterpage.

i tried by giving EnablePageHeadUpdate property for the ajaxmanager to true or false. it didn't help.

also, i tried by adding the ajax setting dynamically in the page load as

```
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(radGdRatings, radGdRatings, RadAjaxLoadingPanel1)
RadAjaxManager1.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(radGdPobabilityMultiplier, radGdPobabilityMultiplier, RadAjaxLoadingPanel1)
```

that also, didn't work.

am giving my page heading like this

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
Manage RA
</asp:Content>
```

can anyone help me out of this? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Please try moving the `RadAjaxManager` to the Master page and then placing a `RadAjaxManagerProxy` on the Content page and using that.  You may be ending up with two RadAjaxManagers on your page somehow.